# UIKitDynamics alter geometry of view?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is it possible to use UIKit dynamics for effects related to internal view geometry and its transformations? Like shrinking/stretching/folding? Or I should look for other tools?

What I want is to combine some behaviors, for example default "snap" with view stretching from point to full-sized rectangle.

Comment: do you mean animations?

Comment: Are you familiar with UIKitDynamics?